# Accesing encrypted HDD after reinstalling OS (Linux)

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk-encryption

I have two drive on my PC:

- SSD
- HDD

OS (Debian) was installed on SSD. HDD was formatted and encrypted from Gnome Disks from installed OS.

In Gnome Disks information about HDD looks like:

[image]

Now I need to install new OS (different Linux distro) on SSD and I do not want to lose any data on HDD.

**Questions:** After installing new OS on SSD do I need anything else other than the password (that I am using now to access HDD) to access all information that is on HDD? Do I need to only mount HDD and enter password or I need to do something else too?

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to remove the encryption temporarily using the old OS, perform the install of the new OS, add back the unencrypted HDD, and then reencrypt the HDD from the new OS.  See [Remove a passphrase or key from a device](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/encrypting-drives-using-LUKS/#_remove_a_passphrase_or_key_from_a_device).  Does the title indicate that you've already removed the old OS?

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you for your comment. I have not removed old OS yet. So, that kind of encryption for decrypting needs something more than passphrase?

Comment: I believe that the encryption salt (the private passkey half) that the disk uses for decryption is stored on the OS disk.  The password is only half the key.  It's kind of like a GPG key.  The password is only the public half.  Once you format the disk for the new OS , you'll lose the private half

Comment: Note that once the disk is unencrypted, you have to move the unencrypted data to some place temporary while you reencrypt the HDD.  Failing to move the data from the HDD will result in Data LOSS.